# Где можно найти книгу самоучитель по android studio программированию, желательно с примерами?

Tags: android-studio

Интересует самоучитель по программированию на андроиде. Где найти современный с примерами? Больше всего будет интереснее видеоуроки, подскажите, где их скачать. На youtube смотрел все, там их не так уж много.

Comment: книга хороша , но платная, да и видео смотреть и за ним повторять еще лучше, если ошибешься , то будешь думать почему не получилось, мне нужны видеоуроки.Где их найти?

Comment: Автор, **Вы изначально сформулировали Ваш именно так: "Где можно найти книгу самоучитель по android studio программированию, желательно с примерами?"** Что касается видеоуроков. Подробные примеры с не менее подробными объяснениями есть и  в книгах. И работать с этими примера ми можно также.При этом изложение материала в книгах более качественное. Хорошие видеоуроки редкость.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста бесплатный литературный источник!Буду благодарен

Comment: Android Studio - IDE, программа, в которой пишут код, а не язык программирования. Для ОС Android программы пишут, как правило на Java + особенности самого фреймворка Android

Answer (score 0):

Начни просто с Java.
И начать лучше с этой [книги](https://toster.ru/q/287046?e=3412325#answer_item_747574). Тогда не придется заморачиваться с поиском книги под Android. Изучив основы Java в Android придется углубить свои познания в потоках(Thread) и в графическом интерфейсе(GUI).

Comment: если говорить о core java в таком случае лучше выбрать Хаббибулина. Java 3е издание.